# How to Close Folder(disabled) in the Vs code workspace like eclipse?

Tags: visual-studio-code

While working on multiple projects sometimes needs to work on different files from the folder of same workspace in VS code. Is there is any way to disable(close) folder like eclipse we do?

[image]

Comment: I'm also looking for this feature unfortunately it is not there yet.

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/63963

Comment: Why not use the `"files.exclude"` setting?