# How to close a folder inside a workspace - vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

Can I close a folder into vscode in a workspace but without loosing the reference?

For example, in Eclipse, I can "close" a folder, and I can "exclude" a folder from a workspace.

The "exclude" mechanism doesn't delete the folder from the operational system.

When I "close", I avoid everything about that folder inside workspace.
And is very easy to reopen the folder.

Comment: When 'Right-Clicking' you can 'Remove Folder from Workspace', which leaves the folder intact on your system, just not visible in the workspace. Is that the behaviour you want?

Comment: @SimonCooper,  I want to close the folder but still with the icon in the workspace to be very easy to reopen it, because I have dozens of projects in my file system, and is boring to find the project again, sometimes I want to search for files in the workspace only inside others projects

Comment: BTW This question is dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51627864/

Comment: @danilo please upvote https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/63963

Answer (score 0):

Here's a workaround that's not ideal, but it's better than nothing. You can modify the project settings to hide the unnecessary folders.

### Problem:

I have a workspace in VS Code with the following folders:

```
folder1
folder2
folder3
folder4
```

I only want to work with **folder3.**

### Solution:

Add the following to the **.vscode/settings.json** file of your workspace:

```
{
  // above your additional configurations
  "files.exclude": {
    "folder1": true,
    "folder2": true,
    "folder4": true
  }
}
```

This will make vscode hide these folders. If you want them back, just remove this code from the file. This works for files too.